# Play a single, random note in Java

Tags: java, audio, midi, javax.sound.midi

I want to play a single, random note in Java. I use the following:

```
Random rand = new Random();

try {
    Synthesizer synth = MidiSystem.getSynthesizer();
    synth.open();

    int note = rand.nextInt(128);
    channels[0].noteOn(note, 80);
} catch (MidiUnavailableException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

but nothing ever happens. Can anyone tell me why?

**EDIT:** I forgot to include `MidiChannel[] channels = synth.getChannels();`

Comment: Where is channels defined? I would expect a line of code such as: MidiChannel[] channels = synth.getChannels(); - also, is your program exiting before the note has time to play?

Answer (score 1):

What's `channels[0]` set to? Since you say "nothing happens" I'm assuming that the program is running and not throwing a `NullPointerException`, which means `channels[0]` has to have a non-null value. I'll bet you forgot to link your existing `channels[0]` object to your `synth` object somehow. Sorry for a non-specific answer, I'll dig a bit more into the API.

**EDIT**: Ok, try changing `channels[0]` to `synth.getChannels()[0]`:

```
    Random rand = new Random();

    try {
        Synthesizer synth = MidiSystem.getSynthesizer();
        synth.open();

        int note = rand.nextInt(128);
        synth.getChannels()[0].noteOn(note, 80);
    } catch (MidiUnavailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I got this to play a random note.

Comment: Unfortunately, my computer stays silent. Sorry about forgetting that code line.

Comment: Is there some other device "using" that channel (i.e., can you unplug all MIDI devices)? Can you try changing the index to `[1]`, `[2]`, etc.?

Comment: All channels are silent.

Comment: If you copy&paste this in main function, the synthesizer will be closed before it plays any note. This could use some thread.sleep or other wait mechanism to play a note.